# Prestashop missing hooks listed in the doc

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I use "Prestashop 1.7.2.3".

If I look in the [doc of Prestashop 1.7 in the hook section](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x).

It lists those hooks:
'displayCheckoutSubtotalDetails' and 'displayCheckoutSummaryTop'.

Now if I do a search for `"Hook::exec('displayCheckout"` in [Prestashop project]/classes or [Prestashop project]/controllers, it does not find '`"Hook::exec('displayCheckoutSubtotalDetails')"` and `"Hook::exec('displayCheckoutSummaryTop')"`.

I am confused, why are those hooks listed if they don't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's executed by the theme itself and not in PHP as indicated in the table.

For example native modules/ps_legalcompliance/ps_legalcompliance.php executes hookDisplayCheckoutSummaryTop($param).

Comment: it is really confusing, because I try to implement it doing : `$this->registerHook('checkoutSubtotalDetails')` in `install()` function like it is described in the doc (http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Displaying+content+on+the+front+office) but having a glance at `modules/ps_legalcompliance/ps_legalcompliance.php` it seems that I should use `$this->registerHook('displayCheckoutSubtotalDetails')` instead to catch it.